# how to test a real purchase when customer no longer has an active payment method

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

When i use iOS auto-renewal subscriptions, is there a way to check if a user doesn't have an active payment method, or do I need to wait a month for Apple to attempt the renewal?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to ask. Please correct your grammar and make your question clearer.

Comment: @sschale if i want to test a real renewal subscribtion when a customer's apple id has no money,what can i do

Comment: essentially the renewal will fail and you will not get an updated subscription end date in your receipt.  In the sandbox auto-renewing subscriptions eventually stop renewing so you can test this condition

Comment: @Paulw11 test account do not to speed money when he buys the product

Comment: No, but in production you don't receive any reason as to why the subscription wasn't renewed either; it could be because there is no valid payment method or it could be that the user decided to cancel the renewal.  Either way the outcome is the same; you reach the termination date in the receipt and stop supplying the service

Comment: @Paulw11 
 The App Store notifies users of any issue so that they can resolve it before the subscription needs to renew, ensuring their subscription isn’t interrupted.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6

Comment: right, so as @sschale said, it isn't your problem.  The subscription either renews or it doesn't.

Comment: @Paulw11 got it ,thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not up to you to be able to be the checker of such things, that lies within Apple's domain. They don't expose any methods for you to make any such checks. They attempt to renew when a subscription is due, and you're not allowed to add a subscription without the user providing input. Further, existing subscriptions are managed outside your app within Settings.